Error deploying spl-token to Solana in mainnet-beta
I was trying to deploy a spl-token to Solana it works in devnet, however, it doesn’t work in mainnet-beta, in which I receive the following error:  
Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?
